# remove logging for certain JBOSS logger

Tags: jboss

How can I remove logging (or set lower level) for certain logger in JBOSS 6.3.

my `console.log` and `server.log` are increasing too fast with a lot of entries from `org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection`

I have tried:

```
  <logger category="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection">
                <level name="ERROR"/>
            </logger>
```

Inside

```
  ../hcname/domain/configuration/domain.conf
```

for profile ha (the profile the app is running on).

log files keep being filled with a lot of warnings anyway.

Here is an example of the logged message:

```
[Server:app] 2018-09-25 16:40:27 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection] (ajp-server-vip1.domain.com/10.128.201.27:8049-19) Closing a result set you left open! Please close it yourself.: java.lang.Throwable: STACKTRACE
[Server:app]  at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.registerResultSet(WrappedStatement.java:1357)
[Server:app]  at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.getResultSet(WrappedStatement.java:740)
[Server:app]  at org.apache.beehive.controls.system.jdbc.JdbcControlImpl.execPreparedStatement(JdbcControlImpl.java:315) [beehive-jdbc-control.jar:1.0.2]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.beehive.controls.system.jdbc.JdbcControlImpl.invoke(JdbcControlImpl.java:225) [beehive-jdbc-control.jar:1.0.2]
[Server:app]  at com.boehringer.serialnumber.jdbc.SubmissionDbCtrlBean.getAllSubmissionsLockedByUser(SubmissionDbCtrlBean.java:737) [SerialNumber.jar:]
[Server:app]  at com.boehringer.serialnumber.custom.SubmissionCtrlImpl.getAllLockedSubmissionsLockedByUser(SubmissionCtrlImpl.java:1209) [SerialNumber.jar:]
[Server:app]  at com.boehringer.serialnumber.custom.SubmissionCtrlBean.getAllLockedSubmissionsLockedByUser(SubmissionCtrlBean.java:242) [SerialNumber.jar:]
[Server:app]  at global.SerialNumberController.onDestroy(SerialNumberController.java:350) [classes:]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowManagedObject.destroy(PageFlowManagedObject.java:104) [beehive-netui-core.jar:1.0.2]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.destroy(FlowController.java:610) [beehive-netui-core.jar:1.0.2]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowManagedObject.valueUnbound(PageFlowManagedObject.java:154) [beehive-netui-core.jar:1.0.2]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.removeAttributeInternal(StandardSession.java:1578) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.expire(StandardSession.java:740) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.expire(StandardSession.java:644) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.invalidate(StandardSession.java:1092) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade.invalidate(StandardSessionFacade.java:150) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:app]  at Controller.logout(Controller.java:304)
[Server:app]  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor511.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_181]
[Server:app]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_181]
[Server:app]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_181]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.invokeActionMethod(FlowController.java:879) [beehive-netui-core.jar:1.0.2]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.getActionMethodForward(FlowController.java:809) [beehive-netui-core.jar:1.0.2]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.internalExecute(FlowController.java:478) [beehive-netui-core.jar:1.0.2]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowController.internalExecute(PageFlowController.java:306) [beehive-netui-core.jar:1.0.2]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.execute(FlowController.java:336) [beehive-netui-core.jar:1.0.2]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.internal.FlowControllerAction.execute(FlowControllerAction.java:52) [beehive-netui-core.jar:1.0.2]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431) [struts.jar:1.2.9]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.access$201(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:97) [beehive-netui-core.jar:1.0.2]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor$ActionRunner.execute(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:2044) [beehive-netui-core.jar:1.0.2]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors.wrapAction(ActionInterceptors.java:91) [beehive-netui-core.jar:1.0.2]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:2116) [beehive-netui-core.jar:1.0.2]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236) [struts.jar:1.2.9]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.processInternal(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:556) [beehive-netui-core.jar:1.0.2]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.process(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:853) [beehive-netui-core.jar:1.0.2]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.AutoRegisterActionServlet.process(AutoRegisterActionServlet.java:631) [beehive-netui-core.jar:1.0.2]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowActionServlet.process(PageFlowActionServlet.java:158) [beehive-netui-core.jar:1.0.2]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414) [struts.jar:1.2.9]
[Server:app]  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
[Server:app]  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.catalina.core.appFilterChain.internalDoFilter(appFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.catalina.core.appFilterChain.doFilter(appFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:app]  at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.event(JBossWebContext.java:91)
[Server:app]  at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(JBossWebContext.java:72)
[Server:app]  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:512) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:app]  at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.5.8.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.5.8.Final-redhat-2]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:490) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:420) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:app]  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
[Server:app]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.7.0_181]
```

Comment: Could you post an example of the logged message?

Comment: Posted an example.

Comment: Excellent thanks. How did you update the configuration? With the web console or CLI?

Comment: I did vim the file and added the config. Restarted HCs and DC afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use CLI or the web console to make changes rather than editing the configuration file manually. This is especially true for logging as there is a `logging.properties` file that is used during boot operations which is updated when management configuration changes are made.

Here is a CLI command that would configure the logger without having to restart the servers.

```
/profile=ha/subsystem=logging/logger=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection:add(level=ERROR)
```